# How to make selected area of a superview transparent

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview

Is there any way we can make only the selected area of a superview transparent? I have a UIView with black (alpha 0.5) background color. I am putting some hollow circles on the UIView and want the underneath UIView to be transparent so that I could see through it. Any idea

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)iFrame andHollowFrames:(NSArray *)iHollowFrames withRadius:(NSNumber *)iRadius {
    if ((self = [super initWithFrame:iFrame]) != nil) {
        self.hollowFrames =  [[NSSet setWithArray:iHollowFrames] allObjects];
        self.hollowCircleRadius = iRadius;
        [self addShadowView];
    }

    return self;
}


- (void)addShadowView {
    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height) cornerRadius:0];

    for (NSValue *point in self.hollowFrames) {
        UIBezierPath *circlePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:CGRectMake(point.CGPointValue.x - self.hollowCircleRadius.floatValue, point.CGPointValue.y - self.hollowCircleRadius.floatValue, 2.0 * self.hollowCircleRadius.floatValue, 2.0 * self.hollowCircleRadius.floatValue) cornerRadius:self.hollowCircleRadius.floatValue];

        [path appendPath:circlePath];
    }

    [path setUsesEvenOddFillRule:YES];

    CAShapeLayer *fillLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    fillLayer.path = path.CGPath;
    fillLayer.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd;
    fillLayer.fillColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    fillLayer.opacity = 0.5;
    [self.layer addSublayer:fillLayer];
}
```

Comment: Provide code how you put the hollow circles on the view.

Comment: Added the coded above.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a UIView subclass solution. In order for this to work you must leave the superviews backgroundColor property as nil witch is the default value. If this UIView-subclass is in the storyboard then make sure you set the background color to "Clear color" in the attributes inspector.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    UIColor *blackBackgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.5];
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, blackBackgroundColor.CGColor);
    CGContextFillRect(ctx, rect);
    CGRect transparentPart = CGRectMake(10, 10, 120, 80);
    CGContextClearRect(ctx, transparentPart);
}
```